# PHP foreach in a deeper array

Tags: php, arrays

How to foreach through a deeper array in PHP? I want to approach 'price' and list all prices below each other.

```
$addons = get_product_addons($product->get_id());
```

When I VAR_DUMP the $addons var, it outputs the below.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Afmeting"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "select"
    ["position"]=>
    int(0)
    ["options"]=>
    array(10) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(8) "70 x 200"
        ["price"]=>
        string(0) "70.00"
        ["min"]=>
        string(0)""
...
```

So I want to output this result:

```
70.00

60.00
```

Etcetera.. *All prices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that piece of code is what you are looking for:

```
foreach($addons as $addon)
{
   echo $addon["options"]["price"].PHP_EOL;
}
```

You do not need to use `foreach` to access nested elements of array. Just use it's key.
`PHP_EOL` is a constant containing newline for your OS. For web application use special formatting suitable for your page (`<br>` e.g.)

Answer (score 1):

You can walk or foreach through the items:

```
<?php

$data =
[
    [
        'name' => 'orange',
        'options' =>
            [
                'price' => '6.00'
            ]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'banana',
        'options' =>
            [
                'price' => '4.00'
            ]
    ]
];


array_walk($data, function($v) {
    echo $v['options']['price'], "\n";
});
```

Output:

```
6.00
4.00
```

Or you could create an array of prices and iterate on that (here using short function syntax):

```
$prices = array_map(fn($v)=>$v['options']['price'], $data);
var_export($prices);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => '6.00',
    1 => '4.00',
  )
```